# Fitting a log-norm distribution for two given percentile values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Assuming that X is log-normal distributed, is it possible to identify its 0th percentile and 100th percentile (or 99.999 approximation) if the 5th percentile and 95th percentile value is given?

How can I program this in scipy to get the low and high value?
I thought conceptually the steps should be
1.) Fit a log normal curve (identify mean and variance) from the 5th percentile = 10 & 95th percentile = 100
2.) Identify the value at low and high (e.g. 99.999%)

Comment: Do you have the mean and standard deviation parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Lognormal means the natural log of your distribution is normal. So, moving between the two you may achieve your goal:

```
import numpy as np
normal_at_5th_percentile = np.log(10)
normal_at_95th_percentile = np.log(100)

# params of related normal distribution
μ = (normal_at_5th_percentile + normal_at_95th_percentile)/2
σ = (normal_at_95th_percentile - μ) / 2

from scipy import stats
# 0.00001 and 0.99999 percentiles of lognormal distribution derived from normal
np.exp(stats.norm.ppf(.00001, loc=μ, scale=σ)), np.exp(stats.norm.ppf(.99999, loc=μ, scale=σ))
(2.715046684206284, 368.31779203565526)
```

Comment: Utilizing the symmetricity of the normal shape to get the expected value is very smart. But can we calculate the variance like this?

Comment: You need to check the basic properties of normal distribution...

Comment: Excuse my insufficient understanding. I've tried to understand the properties better, but given my understanding the variance should be ((normal_at_95th_percentile - μ)^2 + (normal_at_5th_percentile - μ)^2)/2. (But this is only a sample variance.) Could you point me directionally to understand your approach, please? Your method would be super helpful.

Comment: You need to find a way to understand what 5th and 95th percentile means for a normal distribution. Spoiler: μ+/-2σ